# why does this command not work in ubuntu

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I am going over this tutorial: https://github.com/lionaneesh/RasPod/wiki/Setting-up-RasPod

However this command does not work: `sudo modprobe snd_bcm2835`.

I have got a raspberry pi but I am trying this on virtualbox using ubuntu.

Does anyone know why its not working?

Comment: It probably doesn't work because the VirtualBox system doesn't have that sound device.

Answer (score 4):

`snd_bcm2835` is a sound driver for the raspberry hardware. It will not work in virtualbox as virtualbox has a different - virtual - sound architecture.

Testing with virtualbox isn't a good approach, as you need virtualization of the special raspberry hardware. I would try `qemu` instead: http://xecdesign.com/qemu-emulating-raspberry-pi-the-easy-way/